# Which is correct "If I find a good job..." or "If I will find a good job..."?

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions

If I ____ (find) a good job, I'll move to Madrid.

> If I find a good job, I'll move to Madrid.

or is it

> If I will find a good job, I'll move to Madrid.

Or is both? What rule applies here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just never say: If I will, and you will be pretty safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version is correct:

`If I find a good job, I'll move to Madrid.`

It is a [Type 1 conditional](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) which describes a possible thing that may happen in future.

The first clause uses Simple Present, and the second clause (the consequence) uses Future Simple.

Comment: If my brother _____ (not arrive) soon, I'll send him a text message. For this example, is it still the type 1 conditional? If my brother does not arrive soon, I'll send him a text message.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be polite you may use 'will' in the sub-ordinate clause when you apply real time conditions .
For example:1) If you sit here for five minutes I will attend to you.
            2) If you will sit here for five minutes I will attend to you.
Both these two sentences above are grammatically correct, but the second sentence with the usage of will sounds polite.